# Error al usar el espacio de nombres

Tags: php, namespace

Estoy creando un sistema en el que usaremos la carga automática del compositor. Cuando se ejecuta en la terminal de actualización del compositor, genera el directorio de proveedores. La estructura inicial se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Localmente funciona, pero en el servidor remoto no. El autoload.json, está da siguiente forma:

```
{
    "name": "projeto/braspag-sdk",
    "description": "SDK de integração com a loja virtual",
    "type" : "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Nome da empresa - Setor de TI",
            "email": "ti@empresa.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Projeto\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1"
    }
}
```

Para probar si todo estaba bien, creé un directorio llamado `autenticacao/Autenticacao.php`. Mirar:

```
<?php
namespace Projeto\Autenticacao;

class Autenticacao{

    public function __construct(){
        echo "vamos testar";
    }

}
```

Pero cuando se ejecuta en index.php, está dando el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Projeto\Autenticacao' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\braspag\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\braspag\index.php on line 5
```

Vea a continuación cómo es `index.php`:

```
<?php
use Projeto\Autenticacao;
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$autenticacao = new Autenticacao;
```

autoload.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit158a84e74fae995d22470d95a09d55fb::getLoader();
```

No pude entender este error, ya que los directorios son correctos y cuando uso el hipervínculo Visual Code, dirige normalmente. Composer.json se generó en el directorio "/" del servidor remoto. ¿Tiene que copiar los archivos que se generaron en ese directorio (composer.json, composer.lock y el directorio del proveedor) y ponerlo en el directorio donde se encuentran los archivos (/ httpdocs / braspag)? Hice eso y tampoco funcionó.

Perdón por mi español.

Comment: Al parecer cambiaste a mano algunos nombres y puede que te haya faltado corregir estos en algunos lugares. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el contenido del archivo `autoload.php`?

Comment: Tienes razón, Marcos. Hice el ajuste.

Comment: Por favor, agrega el contenido del `autoload.php` en tu pregunta

Comment: Correcto. Agregué el código autoload.php

Comment: También actualicé el texto. Ahora funciona localmente, pero no de forma remota.